# Make sure input1 is not the same as input 2, if so then prompt error

Tags: python, input, function

I'm just curious, how do I make sure that my input1 is not equal to input2? And if that is the case then prompt an error? I am already using a def statement in my code to check that the inputs entered are string and not numerical values, and I don't think I can actually combine it so the def statement does both things.. is there any way?

Comment: Have you tried `!=`, the inequality operator?

Comment: yes^ I tried using that with an if statement, but it didn't work. My whole code stopped working and the error came up each time I tried to input anything at all, whether it was valid or not, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @ConfusedChild **What error?** Did you read it?

Comment: @Patashu The error that i had added: if input1 != input2: print('error')

Comment: @ConfusedChild It would be better to print out input1 and input2 instead of printing 'error', as then you can determine by hand if input1 and input2 are equal or not. (Don't forget that differences like capitalization, whitespace, bad encodings and unicode will cause a difference as well)

Comment: @Patashu, thanks, I actually realised it's because of me using python 2.. Anyways, that is not the problem now as if i use an IF statement, I cannot keep reapeating to ask the user to input something that is valid.

Comment: @ConfusedChild24 Python does not limit the number of while loops you can have in a function, the number of ifs/elifs you can have in a function or the number of functions youcan have in a program. So... Just have both checks in either different or the same function :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function to make sure input is valid:

```
def isvalid(*values):
    for value in values:
        #check a value is invalid 
        if not value in ['pound', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen']: #etc...
            return False
    return True
```

Main Loop:

```
def get_input():
    a = raw_input("A: ")
    b = raw_input("B: ")
    while (not isvalid(a,b) or a != b):
        print("The inputs were not identical! Please try again.")
        a = raw_input("A: ")
        b = raw_input("B: ") 
    print("{0} = {1}".format(a,b))

get_input()
```

Alternatively, you could have only one function to achieve the same functionality:

```
def get_input():
    valid_values = ['pound', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen'] #etc...
    a = raw_input("A: ")
    b = raw_input("B: ")
    while (not (a in valid_values and b in valid_values) or a != b):
        print("The inputs were not valid! Please try again")
        a = raw_input("A: ")
        b = raw_input("B: ") 
    print("{0} = {1}".format(a,b))
```

Note: the `not (a in valid_values and b in valid_values)` is a case of [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). And could be re-written as `not (a in valid_values) or not (b in valid_values)`.

Produces, the following as an example:

```
A: pound
B: orange
The inputs were not valid! Please try again
A: pound
B: euro
The inputs were not valid! Please try again
A: pound
B: pound
pound = pound
>>>
```

To access the values inputted outside `get_input` you can do this

```
def get_input():
        valid_values = ['pound', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen'] #etc...
        a = raw_input("A: ")
        b = raw_input("B: ")
        while (not (a in valid_values and b in valid_values) or a != b):
            print("The inputs were not valid! Please try again")
            a = raw_input("A: ")
            b = raw_input("B: ") 
        print("{0} = {1}".format(a,b))
            return a,b #THIS WAS THE CHANGE
```

And then invoke it like:

```
print("CALLING get_input")
A,B = get_input()
print("CALLED get_input")
#we can now access the result outside of get_input
print(A)
print(B)
```

Will produce:

```
>>> 
CALLING get_input
A: pound
B: pound
pound = pound
CALLED get_input
pound
pound
```

Use `input` instead of `raw_input` in Python 3.x

Comment: Hey, but this is what I meant in my question.. If I use this code then I would not be able to use my def statement listed in my question as then I would not be able to check if the inputs entered are both valid and are NOT identical to each other.

Comment: you could check the inputs are valid by changing the expression in the while loop to `not isvalid(a,b) or a != b`. And have a function like isvalid (added to my answer).

Comment: Omg, so sorry. I still don't get it. I really don't see how I can do both of these using ONE def statement: 1. Check if both the inputs are in valid 2. Check that they are not the same.

Comment: simple change `not isvalid(a,b)` with `not (a in valid_values and b in valid_values)` where `valid_values = ['pound', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen'] #etc...`. Would you like me to update my answer to follow this?

Comment: Hey, I just realised, in your answer.. the variables a and b can't be reffered to anywhere else right?

Comment: You could return the values from the function. i.e `a,b = get_input()` then below the `print("{0} = {1}".format(a,b)` add `return a,b`. And then access `a` and `b` from within the scope of where you called `get_input()`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ConfusedChild24 take a look at my edit, does it make sense now?

Comment: It's good practice to avoid globals where ever possible. IMHO.